# Azure B2C TOTP MFA account not able to re-register

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, multi-factor-authentication, totp

We have an issue, where some users do not seem to finish registering with the authenticator app.
The problem then is that there seems to be no way to redo it.

What i have tried so far.

*Using* "Require re-register multifactor authentication" in the user's account   Authentications methods blade is not doing the trick.
I have read somewhere that this function apparently does not work, as the account was created using a custom policy in B2C.
We had a case where a user had an 'old' account without MFA and using this then enabled them to register with the auth app.

*Creating* a custom policy to not verify the number of devices and force the re-registration.
Problem there is that the number of devices runs out and i get an error.
Currently trying to find a way to reset the number of devices from the custom policy, as we are not allowed to use graphAPI in Prod.

*Deleting* the user seems to be the only thing that works in our case.

There must be a way to get this sorted.  I would have thought there is some sort of mechanism like the password reset, just for TOTP.

Would be great if someone had some ideas.

PS. We are not allowed to use GraphAPI.

Comment: I have a B2C user that I think has TOTP MFA enabled and the user has a "Software OATH token (Preview)" under Authentication methods that can be deleted through the portal. Did you check there?

Comment: Thanks @juunas, that worked, but i do not want to keep doing that for users, so need to find a better way.